# array.prototype.foreach called on null or undefined highcharts

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am working on Highcharts highmaps rich information on click chart.First time load the information by json array and its working fine.But when I am filter data using filters and load chart again it`s give me same error **array.prototype.foreach called on null or undefined highcharts** at below lines.What is solution for this?

```
proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
var points = mapChart.getSelectedPoints();
```

Below link I am using as reference:
        http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/rich-info/

Comment: I see that you reported that problem on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8077 Let the discussion continue there.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this question in case someone else bumps into this problem in the future (even though I saw your problem is solved in github).

I encountered this issue with **Highcharts** when resizing the website (having 2 pie charts and one bar graph). I managed to solve it by wrapping the initialization of the graphs in a **document.ready**:

```
$(() => {
    controller.initializePieHighChart();
    controller.initializeBarHighChart();
});
```